# How to disable Eclipse PDT auto-format code when pasting

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt, autoformatting

I'm using Eclipse Indigo 3.7.0 with PDT for PHP develpment.
When I copy/paste some code, Eclipse automatically format it.

For example, copying this :

```
if ($distance > 50 && $distance  <= 100)    {$local_score = 8;}
if ($distance > 100 && $distance <= 200)    {$local_score = 6;}
```

Is pasted in this :

```
if ($distance > 50 && $distance  <= 100)    {
    $local_score = 8;
}
if ($distance > 100 && $distance <= 200)    {
    $local_score = 6;
}
```

Any idea on how to disable this ?
Best Regards.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's really bad...
Try this.
Open workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.php.ui.prefs by your text editor.
Add "smartPaste=true".

(note that I'm not aware of side effect)

Comment: I tried this and it`s working well. No side effect noticed for now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be "smartPaste=false", instead of "true" ??
"true" didn't work for me, but "false" did.
Also, you can find the corresponding configuration option through Eclipse preferences: Window -> Preferences -> PHP - > Editor -> Typing -> Uncheck "When Pasting Adjust Indentation" (courtesy of http://roadzy.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-disable-auto-formatting-when.html)

Comment: Pay attention to "answered Jul 5 '11 at 11:28". On that day, UI had not been implemented yet. This is an old story.

Answer (score 15):

- Go to Window / Preferences
- Then select page Java / Editor / Typing
- Then unselect checkbox "When pasting" / "Adjust indentation".

Comment: This did not work under Eclipse `Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)`.

Comment: Yes, it very much indeed does work with `Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)`. This should be the preferred solution. (If it does not work for you, undo the change to the .ui.prefs file which might have caused the error)

Comment: This question is regarding PDT (PHP Developer Tools), and while this may be obvious to some, the second step of this answer should be `Then select page *PHP* (not Java) / Editor / Typing`. This still works in 4.6.2.